# Visual Studio 2013 New Project Visual C# Service-based Database item is missing

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, vs-community-edition

I am running Visual Studio Community 2013 and one time when following tutorial about database projects I noticed that I dont have item.
**New Project -> Visual C# -> Data -> Service-based Database**

I dont even have a Data tab.
I have image but cant post it until I will have 10 reputation...

I have tried to delete folders:

> ...Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates 
> ...Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache

then use

```
devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates
```

I have also tried to repair Microsoft Visual Studio from Add/Remove programs and Install **SQL DATA TOOLS** but problem still exists.

Any 1 have idea how to solve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Service Based Database is not a Project, but a File template. So either on an existing project or on a new blank Class Library project use the <kbd>Add new Item...</kbd> option and you should be able to find the correct file template.

See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx